# Como usar valores de uma Classe do Model em outro no Django?

Tags: python, django

Fala galera, ainda não encontrei um norte nem como pesquisar sobre, então vou recorrer ao SO.

Tenho o seguinte no meu models.py, Ingrediente e Produto:

```
class Ingrediente(models.Model):
    produtor = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=10)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    quantidade = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    custo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

e

```
class Produto(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    custo_produto = #aqui minha dúvida
    porcentagem_lucro = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    valor_venda = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    ingredientes = models.ManyToManyField(Ingrediente)
```

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para que esse `custo_produto` seja uma soma do `custo` das instâncias de `Ingrediente` que forem associadas ao `Produto`.

Entendem? A soma do custo dos ingredientes é o custo do produto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse é um caso legal para se usar um `property` - quando para o código que for usar suas instâncias, vai haver simplesmente a leitura do atributo, mas, na classe, um método é executado automaticamente.

Note que a principal diferença é que nesse caso, o `custo_produto` vai existir como atributo do objeto, mas não vai existir na tabela correspondente a esse modelo no banco de dados - apenas o código do lado do Python vai calcular esse valor:

Dá pra fazer com várias linhas, fica mais legível:

```
class Produto(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    porcentagem_lucro = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    valor_venda = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    ingredientes = models.ManyToManyField(Ingrediente)

    @property
    def custo_produto(self):
          total = 0
          for ingrediente in self.ingredientes.all():
               total += ingredientes.custo
           return total
```

Como ele o `.custo_produto` não vai fazer parte dos `fields`, é melhor colocar a sua declaração por último, para não interferir na declaração dos fields - mas isso é mais estético que qualquer outra coisa.

Também se pode usar uma sintaxe mais avançada do Python, com generator expression, `sum` e `lambda`, para fazer a mesma coisa em uma única linha:

```
class Produto(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    custo_produto = property(lambda self: sum(ingr.custo for ingr in self.ingredientes.all() ))
    porcentagem_lucro = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    valor_venda = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    ingredientes = models.ManyToManyField(Ingrediente)
```

Eu expliquei mais sobre properties em outra resposta recente - lá, sem ser classes específicas do Django: [Definição e uso do @property](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/364596/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-uso-do-property/364600#364600)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas ainda tive problemas. Testei as duas soluções, copiando o código para garantir que não erraria, e obtive um erro: "'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable". Vale lembrar que, no meu template, eu usei {{ produtos.custo_produto }}, afim de retornar esse valor que você citou, seria assim ?

Comment: o uso entre duas chaves é para usar num template - é _outra linguagem_ de programação - aqui estamos falando da parte em Python. Você está tentando ver o custo_produto de uma instância (um produto específico), ou direto da classe? Na classe vai dar erro.

Deixa eu dar uma olhada para instâncias se precisa alguma outra coisa. (O Django costuma ser "pythonico", mas as vezes eles pisam na bola)

Comment: entendo jsbueno, a ideia é jogar esse valor para o template do django, aí pensei nessa sintaxe pois é a mesma que uso para os outros atributos da classe Produto. Na página especificamente eu puxo os detalhes de cada instância, como seu nome, descrição, e agora teria também seu custo_produto

Comment: Pronto - achei o problema - o ManyTMany field não é iterável em si - ele é um "QuerySet" do Django - precisa chamar o método `.all()` nele para que ele devolva um iterável para todos os objetos relacionados. Alterei o código para fazer isso.

Comment: Dentro do template também dá pra usar direto agora: `{{ produto.custo_produto }} `

Comment: Vou testar agora mesmo!

Comment: Isso foi perfeito chefe, só mais duas coisas para dizer: 1 - no for, o correto é "ingredientes" com "s", e não sem o "s" (testado e confirmado hahaha). 2 - Se puder me sugerir onde aprender mais sobre isso e como chegaste a essa solução, agradeço, estou lendo tua outra resposta (que voce linkou, sobre properties). Valeu! Funcionando!

Comment: A resposta que liguei, sobre "property" é um bom começo. O restante é prática de programação mesmo  - o ideal é que  ter desenvoltura o suficiente para se chegar na primeira solução sem ter nenhuma dúvida.  A segunda solução é mais específica de Python.

Comment: Quanto a variável no `for`, o nome da variável é criado no proprio `for` então é `ingrediente` mesmo - quem escreve o `for` que dá o nome.  - aí, se em vez de um comando Python fosse uma frase em ingles, a tardução seria  `para [cada] ingrediente em ingredientes:` (e não `para [cada] ingredientes em ingredientes`) Podia ser `a`, `x`, `paralelepipedo` - funcionaria do mesmo jeito.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, 
Pelo que eu entendi, você terá que fazer um `forloop` **mais ou menos** assim :

**Obs: O código não está correto**

```
class Ingrediente() # a classe

    custoTotal = 0
    for i in Ingrediente # voce chama a classe, ela tem que contar ou use .COUNT
         custoTotal= custoTotal+Ingrediente.custo #especifica o nome da variavel 
    endfor
return custototal # retorna depois do loop com o total

class Produto(models.Model):
nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
custo_produto = custototal #os totais somados
...
```

Links de Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates

Comment: negativando por estr em pseudocódigo, a referencia ao link tambḿ fala de laços em templtes, que não é o caso, e você repetiu a identação errada da edição da pergunta original.  apesar da ideia principal estar correta - a falta das especificidades da linguagem, palavras chave inexistentes, uso sem sentido de "class", tenho que alertar outros leitores que estejam aprendendo Python.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, tentei responder o mais rápido possível. Na próxima vez perguntarei para que possa fazer uma resposta mais elaborada.