# Como acessar um atributo privado em Python, sendo que criei um objeto a partir de de outra classe que tem atributos privados também

Tags: python

Criei um objeto a partir da classe `Especificacoes`, e ao criar um obejto da classe `Geradores`, passei o objeto criado a partir de `Especificacoes` como parâmetro para classe `Geradores`. Observe que o atributo `self.__especificacoes` recebe como valor um objeto que tem vários atributos privados. Como acessá-los? Não consigo.

```
class Geradores:
  def __init__(self, nome, especificacoes):
    self.__nome = nome
    self.__especificacoes = especificacoes
    self.__qtd_tanque = 400
    self.__liga_desliga = 'Desligado'


  def get_especificacoes(self):
    return self.__especificacoes


class Especificacoes:
  def __init__(self, potencia, capac_ger_energia, tamanho_tanque):
    self.__potencia = potencia
    self.__capac_ger_energia = capac_ger_energia
    self.__tamanho_tanque = tamanho_tanque


espec_g1 = Especificacoes(95, 8000, 500)
g1 = Geradores('G1', espec_g1)

print(g1.get_especificacoes())
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar detalhadamente o problema, descrevendo o que tentou e onde está a dificuldade atual, de preferência com um [mcve]. Estudar a postagem disponível neste link pode fazer uma diferença muito positiva no seu aproveitamento do site: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Comment: Se você deseja acessar um atributo privado, normalmente optamos por criar um getter, assim o acesso fica sendo somente leitura.

Comment: Na verdade não existem campos privados em Python. O que acontece é que quando o nome começa com dois `_`, ele ativa o *name mangling*, que "muda internamente" os nomes dos atributos. Mas ainda é possível acessá-los, tente fazer `print(g1.get_especificacoes()._Especificacoes__potencia)` - ou ainda `g1.get_especificacoes()._Especificacoes__potencia = 10` para mudar o valor, [veja](https://ideone.com/McaqVl). Criar um *getter*, como sugerido acima, tem mais a ver com "facilitar" o acesso, mas não impede que o valor seja mudado... Sugiro uma lida [nesta resposta](/a/375844/112052) para saber mais

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, entenda que na verdade não existem campos privados em Python. Isso é dito na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) (ênfase minha):

> *"Private" instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object **don't exist in Python**.*

O que existe é uma **convenção** de se usar nomes de variáveis/métodos/etc começando com `_` para indicar que eles não fazem parte da API pública e portanto não devem ser acessados diretamente, pois são detalhes internos de implementação que podem inclusive mudar sem aviso.

Mas também existe um mecanismo chamado [*name mangling*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-5) para identificadores que começam com **dois** `_`: qualquer identificador com o nome na forma `__campo` se torna `_nomedaclasse__campo`. Mas isso não torna o campo privado, pois ainda é possível acessá-lo. Ex:

```
class Teste:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.__valor = valor    

t = Teste(10)
print(t._Teste__valor) # 10
t._Teste__valor = 'xyz'; # mudando o valor, mesmo ele sendo "privado"
print(t._Teste__valor) # xyz
# mostra os campos de t
print(vars(t)) # {'_Teste__valor': 'xyz'}
```

---

Portanto, no seu caso ainda seria possível acessar (e alterar) os campos da classe `Especificacoes`:

```
espec_g1 = Especificacoes(95, 8000, 500)
g1 = Geradores('G1', espec_g1)

print(g1.get_especificacoes()._Especificacoes__potencia) # 95

g1.get_especificacoes()._Especificacoes__potencia = 10
print(g1.get_especificacoes()._Especificacoes__potencia) # 10
```

Mas se você precisa acessar esses campos fora da classe, talvez eles não devessem ser "privados". Já para exibir as especificações, você pode ter um método que já retorna a string formatada com as informações desejadas:

```
class Geradores:
    def __init__(self, nome, especificacoes):
        self.nome = nome
        self.especificacoes = especificacoes
        self.qtd_tanque = 400
        self.liga_desliga = 'Desligado'

    # opção 1, ter um método que retorna as especificações já formatadas
    def get_specs(self):
        return f'Potência={self.especificacoes.potencia}, Capacidade={self.especificacoes.capac_ger_energia}, Tanque={self.especificacoes.tamanho_tanque}'

class Especificacoes:
    def __init__(self, potencia, capac_ger_energia, tamanho_tanque):
        self.potencia = potencia
        self.capac_ger_energia = capac_ger_energia
        self.tamanho_tanque = tamanho_tanque

    # opção 2: ao imprimir as especificações, retorna uma string formatada com os dados
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Potência={self.potencia}, Capacidade={self.capac_ger_energia}, Tanque={self.tamanho_tanque}'

g1 = Geradores('G1', Especificacoes(95, 8000, 500))

# chamar o método get_specs(), que já traz as especificações formatadas
print(g1.get_specs()) # Potência=95, Capacidade=8000, Tanque=500

# imprimir Especificacoes diretamente, é chamado o método __repr__
print(g1.especificacoes) # Potência=95, Capacidade=8000, Tanque=500
```

Enfim, como em Python não existe o conceito de `private` (similar a outras linguagens, como Java e C#), talvez seja melhor inicialmente deixar os campos assim mesmo, sem os `_` na frente do nome. Assim você pode acessá-los diretamente (ex: `g1.especificacoes.potencia`). A menos, é claro, que esses campos sejam detalhes internos de implementação que podem mudar sem aviso futuramente - e nesse caso, talvez seja melhor usar uma variação da opção 2 acima: ter um método que retorna as informações necessárias (algo como `get_detalhes_espec()` ou algo assim, que já retorna os dados formatados para as demais classes).

E futuramente, se você precisar de alguma lógica adicional nesses campos, aí [você pode até criar *properties*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364596/112052) (leia mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187187/112052)), que é uma forma de simular o *getter* e *setter* de outras linguagens (mas não crie um *getter* sem necessidade - se ele só retorna o campo e nada mais, não há de fato um ganho em criar a *property*). E lembre-se que, de qualquer forma, se você criar apenas o *getter*, isso não impede que o campo seja modificado, pois nada é realmente privado.